# How to use Popen using Python on Windows?

Tags: python, powershell

I am trying out an example Pipe program using Python on Windows

```
import subprocess

p1 = subprocess.Popen(["powershell", "Get-ChildItem C:\\dev\\python"],  stdout=subprocess.PIPE);

p2 = subprocess.Popen(["powershell", "Select-String", "py"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE);
p1.stdout.close();

p2_output = p2.communicate()[0];
print(p2_output);
```

However, it errors with the following

```
cmdlet Select-String at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Path[0]: b"\r\nSelect-String : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty array.\nAt line:1 char:1\n+ Select-String py\n+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Select-String], ParameterBindingValidationException\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyArrayNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectStringCommand\n \n"
```

I expect the program to work as 'stdin' for P2 takes the output of P1's 'stdout'.  Not sure what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Do you expect to use interactive python shell?

Answer (score 0):

You use Popen correctly, however PowerShell's pipeline between 2 command-lets is very different in its nature from a regular pipeline between processes. PowerShell transfers objects. Look more in the [Understanding pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/understanding-the-powershell-pipeline?view=powershell-6) document.

Unfortunately this feature cannot be used for communication between separate PowerShell processes using system pipeline.

So this command will fail exactly the same way as it fails in your code:

`powershell Get-ChildItem C:\dev\python | powershell Select-String py`

```
cmdlet Select-String at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Path[0]:
Select-String : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty array.
At line:1 char:1
+ Select-String -Pattern py
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Select-String], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyArrayNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectStringCommand
```

You should use Popen to work with the single PowerShell process and let PowerShell to handle pipelining:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen("powershell Get-ChildItem C:\\dev\\python | Select-String py", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

p_output = p.communicate()[0].decode()
print(p_output)
```

P.S. Don't use `;` in Python